# vsFTPd connection to ubuntu instance

Tags: networking, server, ftp, vsftpd

I'm running Ubuntu on a instance on the university server. I've installed vsFTPd and added a new user.

I uncommented the following parameters in the vsftpd.conf:

```
write_enable=YES 
chroot_local_user=YES
```

and added a user with:

```
sudo adduser name

sudo chmod a-w /home/name/
```

I can connect to my instance with filezilla. But when I want to send a file to my ubuntu instance the following error message appears in filezilla:

```
553 Could not create file
```

I tried to add the parameter `allow_writeable_chroots=YES` to the config, but then I can't even connect to the instance.

Robin

Answer (score 0):

`sudo chmod a-w /home/name/` makes `/home/name` not writrable by everyone, including the owner. Unfortunately this is a prerequisite for the `chroot_local_user` option. You can create a folder inside `/home/name` and set the rights accordingly to allow uploads.